# ReactJs logging received props array shows empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, react-component

My code displays a list of users through these  components:

> Users.js

```
class Users extends Component {
  state = {
    usersInformation: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getUsersDataFromDB()
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          usersInformation: result.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("(1) Outside error:", error));
  }

  render() {
    console.log("this.state.usersInformation");
    console.log(this.state.usersInformation);
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Fragment>
          <UsersList usersInformation={this.state.usersInformation} />
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> UsersList.js

```
class UsersList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pagesCount:2,
      currentPage: 0,
      pageSize: 5
    };

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount: this.props.usersInformation')
    console.log(this.props.usersInformation)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps: this.props.usersInformation')
    console.log(this.props.usersInformation)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Row>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader>
              <i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Admins{" "}
              <small className="text-muted">
                La liste complète des admins{" "}
              </small>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Table responsive hover>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Role</th>
                    {/* TODO: Derniere == Dernière problem with UTF */}
                    <th scope="col">Derniere connexion</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  {this.props.usersInformation
                    .slice(
                      this.state.currentPage * this.state.pageSize,
                      (this.state.currentPage + 1) * this.state.pageSize
                    )
                    .map(userInformation => {
                      return (
                        <tr key={userInformation.id.toString()}>
                          <td>{userInformation.id}</td>
                          <td>{userInformation.nom}</td>
                          <td>{userInformation.email}</td>
                          <td>{userInformation.role}</td>
                          <td>{userInformation.derniereCnx}</td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </CardBody>

          </Card>
        </Row>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

which gives the following result :
[image]
In User.js, I retrieve the usersInformation from database and pass it as props to UsersList.
The problem is that when I log the **usersInformation** in **UserList.js**, inside the two methods **componentWillReceiveProps** and **componentDidMount**, they both show an empty array, ***despite the fact that the user information gets displayed perfectly:***

```
Users.js:37 this.state.usersInformation
Users.js:38 []
UsersList.js:20 componentDidMount:this.props.usersInformation
UsersList.js:21 []
Users.js:37 this.state.usersInformation
Users.js:38 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
UsersList.js:25 componentWillReceiveProps: this.props.usersInformation
UsersList.js:26 []
```

So I suppose this is a problem of the lifeCycle of the React component UsersList?
Which lifecycle method should I use in order to be able to log the usersInformation array?

Comment: can you try nextProps instead of this.props.

```componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps: this.props.usersInformation')
    console.log(nextProps.usersInformation)
  }```

Comment: @MohitPrakash Thank you that solved the issue!